# Android app development (daily journal type)

Tags: android, application-design, android-development, app

I want to get help from you all about building an android app that is capable of logging daily journal type data. I want to have these feature primarily in the app:

1. Capable of logging the daily logs.
2. Some way to save data to some cloud storage app like, Google drive
3. Login with eMail feature for password recovery
4. In built App lock
5. Backup could have been done as a text file
6. Search possible by date, by keywords [keywords are something like hashtags or labels so that user can tag days as happy days, sad days etc *(like people do in their blogs sometimes)*]
7. Last but not least, having some nice UI

I'm really newbie so I don't know where to start and what all things I need to learn in order to make this project.
**All you people have to do is list down the things I should learn to make this project into reality**

PS:-

- I am doing this for my own curiosity and fun.
- It would be even more good if you suggest some things from your experience.

I would be really thankful to you all.

Comment: see [Where to start?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6367/31260) and  [Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7538/31260)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

First app comes to mind is Evernote (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evernote&hl=de&gl=US), so maybe you want to try to search for "android evernote clone github".

If you find a nice project, clone it to your desktop and open it in Android Studio. After a week of reading the code you will realize how complex such a small app is and you will know if you are dedicated enough to make your own.

Good luck!